# GNU LD: Override funtions in static library

Tags: linker, binutils

I have the following problem:

In some commercial project (ARM Cortex-M), we have pre-compiled libraries from a supplier.

The library contains code from different suppliers; some library functions use the standard `malloc()` function call, while others use the memory allocator of the operating system (in the example below: `os_malloc()`).

The `malloc()` function is taken from the `libc.a` standard library.

Both implementations seem to disturb each other. For this reason I'd like to replace the default `malloc()` (and `free()`) implementation by something like this:

```
void * malloc(uint32_t size)
{
    return os_malloc(size);
}

void free(void * ptr)
{
    os_free(ptr);
}
```

However, in this case I would have to remove the object file containing `malloc()` and `free()` from the `libc.a` library file - what I also don't want to do.

Is there a possibility to tell the GNU linker not to take some symbol from a library if it is already defined outside the library?

... or a possibility to tell the linker not to take a certain object file from a library?

... or a possibility to do something like `PROVIDE(malloc = os_malloc);` in the linker script although the symbol `malloc` is defined in some library?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, in this case I would have to remove the object file containing malloc() and free() from the libc.a library file - what I also don't want to do.

That statement is false, and demonstrates that you do not understand how linkers work with archive libraries.

You *do not* in fact need to remove anything from `libc.a` (though the replacement may not work for other reasons).

Here is a good [explainer](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already worked with a linker (a commercial linker for TriCore or PowerPC - I don't remember) that refused linking with the message "duplicate symbol" if a library file contained a symbol that also occurs in an object file. This is why I asked the question. However, if it is guaranteed that GNU ld takes the symbol from the object file in such a case, I will simply implement the wrappers shown in my question ...